# Android listview adapter with button

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-arrayadapter, android-button

I have a problem with my Android application which I'm developing in C#. I have a **ListActivity** and an **ArrayAdapter** and inside ListActivity i have custom views with a TextView and a **Button**. 
This button should start new activities, get the results from the activities (mostly text inputs), and do something in the background, and then update the TextView's text.

I'm using **ViewHolder pattern** in the ArrayAdapter, and Command Pattern for the background operations.

My problem is that I can't find a way how to **update the TextViews inside ArrayAdapter**, since I have the results of the activities in the ListActivity. I tried to create an event in ListActivity and subscribed to it inside ArrayAdapter but I think it is not an optimal solution to this problem.

Could you suggest something better implementation to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` does nothing?

Comment: I don't know the exact position of the element so i can't modify it, and call notifyDataSetChanged()